# Using jquery to change <span> html to <tr>...</tr>

Tags: jquery, jsp

*Disclaimer: HTML, JQuery, Ajax skill level — rubbish. Always been a thick client person.*

I've got a form that allows the user to enter a customer code and an email address. I want to display the customer's name when the customer code is valid. I'll blunder my way through Ajax and Spring MVC to do that, but as a first step, I figured I'd use a jquery function to add a row to the table under the customer code. I can't get it to work, however.

Here's my JSP:

```
<%@include file="/common/header.jsp" %>
<h1>
    <a href="/customerEmailList.do"><spring:message code="customer.email.title"/></a>
    <span class="breadcrumb"><spring:message code="ui.breadcrumb.separator"/></span>
    <spring:message code="action.add"/>
</h1>
<form:form action="customerEmailAdd.do" commandName="customerEmailEntry">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><form:errors cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><spring:message code="customer.email.code"/> <span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
            <td><form:input id="customerCode" path="customerCode" maxlength="8" size="10"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="customerCode" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>
        <span id="identifiedCustomer">
        </span>
        <tr>
            <td><spring:message code="customer.email.edit.field"/> <span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
            <td><form:input path="emailAddress" maxlength="255" size="50"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="emailAddress" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <hr/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="right">
                <input type="submit" class="green-button" value="<spring:message code="button.save"/>"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $ ( document ).ready ( function () {
        $ ( '#identifiedCustomer' ).html ( '<tr><td>Hello, world</td></tr>' );
    } );    
</script>

<%@include file="/common/footer.jsp" %>
```

jquery (1.8.3) is being pulled in via the common header.

When the form loads, the text *Hello, world* is displayed, but it's not a new table row. It shows up before the table. I would have expected it to create a new row between the `customerCode` and `emailAddress` field rows.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `.html` use `.replaceWith`

`.html` changes the contents of the span but does not remove them.  The span in the middle of the table and with its own `<tr>` is invalid.  `.replaceWith` will create a new element and remove the `<span>` from the DOM.

However, depending upon how the DOM is structured this may cause problems because the span starts at an invalid spot.  Why not juse use `<tr id="identifiedCustomer">` instead of `<span>`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just have a `span` in the middle of a `table`. That's invalid HTML. You'll have to use a `tr` instead:

```
<tr>
    <td><spring:message code="customer.email.code"/> <span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
    <td><form:input id="customerCode" path="customerCode" maxlength="8" size="10"/></td>
    <td><form:errors path="customerCode" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
<tr id="identifiedCustomer"></tr>
<tr>
    <td><spring:message code="customer.email.edit.field"/> <span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
    <td><form:input path="emailAddress" maxlength="255" size="50"/></td>
    <td><form:errors path="emailAddress" cssClass="error"/></td>
</tr>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready ( function () {
    $('#identifiedCustomer').html('<td>Hello, world</td>');
});
```

Comment: Bingo. Perfect. Thanks, Joseph.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is

```
$('table tbody').append('<tr><td>Hello, world</td></tr>');
```

that will select the tbody of the table and append the new row to the end.

Ideally you would add an ID to the table so you don't end up adding a new row to every table on the page.

Comment: I don't want the new row at the end — I want it to appear under the customer code.